# Has anyone dealt with leonlite low voltage ground lights?

Tags: transformer

I am having trouble with finding the right transformer for a set of 7w led ground lights I bought on Amazon, apparently they are not compatible with Leon lights

Any thought?

Comment: Well it would help to know what you're dealing with.  Link or photograph the "transformer", the Leon lights, and the Amazon items...

Comment: Check this out at Amazon.com
LEONLITE 7W In-Ground Landscape Lighting, IP67 Waterproof LED Outdoor Well Light, UL Listed Linkable Pathway Lights, 12-24V, 3000K Warm White, for Yard, Garden, Patio, Pack of 6 https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07MB1N6Q2/ref=cm_sw_r_other_apa_i_PgLLEb8NT16EG

Comment: 12V Magnitude Magnetic Dimmable LED Driver Transformer Hardwired Under Cabinet Lighting 100 Watt - Inspired LED https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0058WTHO0/ref=cm_sw_r_fm_apa_i_0YeNEbR9BHFKD